# Apache-Airflow - Task is in the none state when running DAG

Tags: airflow, windows-subsystem-for-linux, directed-acyclic-graphs

*Just started with airflow and wanted to run simple dag with BashOperator that outputs 'Hello' to console*
I noticed that my status is indefinitely stuck in 'Running'

When I go on task details, I get this:

**Task is in the 'None' state which is not a valid state for execution. The task must be cleared in order to be run.**

Any suggestions or hints are much appreciated.

Dag:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

default_args = {
    'owner': 'dude_whose_doors_open_like_this_-W-',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': days_ago(2),
    'email': ['yessure@gmail.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}
dag = DAG(
    'Test',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Test',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1)
)

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='ECHO',
    bash_command='echo "Hello"',
    dag=dag
)

t1
```

Comment: schedule_interval needs to be a cron schedule such as  30 1 * * *  or @daily

Comment: No it doesn't - it can be also datetime.timedelta object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to solve it by adding `'start_date': dt(1970, 1, 1)`,
to default args object
and adding `schedule_interval=None` to my dag object

Answer (score 1):

Could you remove the last line of `t1`- this isn't necessary. Also `start_date`shouldn't be set dynamically - this can lead to problems with the scheduling.